# Resolving multiple inheritance ambiguity with enable_if

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, name-lookup, ambiguous-call

I have an event source base class, which defines a function to add listeners, and I'm trying to use a template argument to resolve ambiguity. But that doesn't seem to work - it always uses the function from the first base class and then complains that template parameters don't match:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class Event>
class EventSource
{
public:

  class Listener
  {
  public:
      virtual void handle( const Event& e ) = 0;
  };

  template<class EventType>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Event, EventType>::value, void>::type
  addListener( Listener* ptr );
};

class Event1 {};
class Event2 {};

class MultiListener : public EventSource<Event1>::Listener, public EventSource<Event2>::Listener
{
public:
    void handle( const Event1& e );
    void handle( const Event2& e );
};

class MultiSource : public EventSource<Event1>, public EventSource<Event2>
{
public:
    void addMultiListener( MultiListener* ptr )
    {
        addListener<Event1>( ptr );
        addListener<Event2>( ptr ); // this line causes error
    }
};
```

Why does this not fall under SFINAE?

I know I can explicitly specify base class, but templates look much better than `EventSource<Event1>::addListener(...)`.

Comment: You might have simplify your case to [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23fcf68efa1696c1)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that it doesn't work even with regular overloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both lines cause error, as name look-up is ambiguous (before checking if overloads are viable).

You might fix issue by using `using`

```
class MultiSource : public EventSource<Event1>, public EventSource<Event2>
{
    using EventSource<Event1>::addListener;
    using EventSource<Event2>::addListener;
public:
    void addMultiListener( MultiListener* ptr )
    {
        addListener<Event1>( ptr );
        addListener<Event2>( ptr );
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8769d782ad3dc01)

Comment: So it looks up the namespace before checking for overloads in that namespace? I guess I'm better off explicitly specifying base class then, thanks.

Comment: Variadic template might help: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff0557a131387f19)

Comment: Interesting idea! I'll consider that if I find the need for more multi-listeners.